# Opentok / Vonage screenshot sample for Android return solid green image

Tags: api, video, screenshot, opentok, vonage

We tried the [code sample](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/tree/main/Live-Photo-Capture-Kotlin) provided by Opentok for capturing screenshot of publisher but it is not working. It returns solid green screen. Can some one please provide working code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the below code and let me know if you are able to take the publisher's snapshot?

```
(publisher?.view as TextureView).bitmap //captures publisher's snapshot

(subscriber?.view as TextureView).bitmap //captures subscriber's snapshot
```

To use the above, please make sure to enable textureView inside sessionOptions as below:-

```
session = Session.Builder(this, apiKey, sessionId).sessionOptions(object : Session.SessionOptions() {
            
            override fun useTextureViews(): Boolean {
                return true
            }
        }).build().also {
            it.setSessionListener(sessionListener)
            it.connect(token)
        }
```

Let me know how it goes.